How to hide scroll overflow after a certain position
I'm trying to create a scrollbar that a sticky header
.sidebar {
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #f1f2f7; 
    padding: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
}

.sidebar-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; 
    background-color: #f1f2f7; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center; 
}

Because I have padding pushing the sidebar-header down this means that when I scroll down far enough the text will start to appear above it. Ideally I'd like this to stay hidden as soon as it reaches the sticky header

one solution I found was to remove the overflow-y property from the sidebar and add it to  a class for sidebar content, which fixes this but makes the scrollbar appear inwards on the sidebar which isn't ideal
.sidebar-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}


Is there a simple and elegant solution that I'm missing here? This seems like it would be a common issue

Please add enough relevant code to create an actual [mre]

Remove the padding-top from .sidebar, and add it to .sidebar-header instead?

Without seeing your html it's hard to define "elegant".
position: sticky keeps the element in the flow of the first ancestor with position: relative so elegant could just be a matter of cleaning up unwanted default styling, in your case the padding.
Also you're introducing Flex containers which can be helpful, but I'd suggest not using flex until you get the scrolling nailed down.
That way when you add the flex options you'll know that if anything starts misbehaving it's due to flex.


div {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<div>
  <h2>
    Sidebar Title
  </h2>
  <p>First Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>Last Content</p>
</div>



